# Using "hasn't he" in question tags

Tags: questions, negation, tag-questions

I read about [question tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question), and they give this example:

> He *has* a book, **hasn't he**?

I think that using **doesn't he?** would be more logical and in accordance to modern grammar.
Because I cannot say "He **hasn't** a book." or "**Hasn't** he a book?" — it's outdated. You always say "He **doesn't** have a book." or "**Doesn't** he have a book?"

Comment: I think this depends on whether you're British or American. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Hasn%27t+he+any%3Aeng_gb_2012%2CHasn%27t+he+any%3Aeng_us_2012%2CDoesn%27t+he+have+any%3Aeng_gb_2012%2CDoesn%27t+he+have+any%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHas%20not%20he%20any%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHas%20not%20he%20any%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDoes%20not%20he%20have%20any%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDoes%20not%20he%20have%20any%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: The verbs *have* and *be* are preserved in question tags. Other verbs may be preserved, but are generally switched to *do*. I think. That's off the top of my head, which is why it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: To my British ear, it sounds a bit off to use the question tag *"doesn't he?"* after OP's specific example (which I must admit I find difficult to contextualise). But I certainly think the "verb switch" is more natural in, say, [*"I have cancer, don't I?"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22have+cancer+don't+I%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). There are 107 hits in Google Books for that version, but none at all for *"I have cancer, **haven't** I?"*

Comment: Tottie and Hoffmann 2006 argue that "British English normally also has DO-tags as code for HAVE in anchor clauses [..] but HAVE anchors are rare." cf. their example (46) ". . . ooh, oh you have this, don’t you? (BNC-SDEM)"

Comment: John hasn't passed his exams.
I may come tomorrow.
I need to attend the wedding party.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page specifically notes that

> If the main verb is *to have*, either solution *[hasn't he?, doesn't he?]* is possible.

My American ear says this is wrong, and *doesn't he?* is the only correct tag, but I certainly recognize *hasn't he?* as valid British-English usage.

Answer (score 1):

He has a book, doesn't he?
He has good news, doesn't he?

He has to go, hasn't he?
He has gone shopping, hasn't he?

- When has is used for posession (has a book) we use the tag "doesn't".
- When has is used as an auxiliary or irregular verb (he has to go/ has been shopping etc) we use the tag "hasn't".

And I believe this rule applies to UK English and American English Grammar and Spelling.

Answer (score 0):

I think if the "has" acts like an auxiliary, it must take hasn't. For instance. He has taken my pen. In this statement, the "has" is an auxiliary verb to "taken". Therefore, it can't take "doesn't he"? But it should rather be "hasn't he?" But looking at this statement " He has a book", the "has" is the main verb of the statement. Therefore using "hasn't he?" won't be appropriate but rather must use "doesn't he?"