# Proper tag question for "has to" and "have to"

Tags: grammar, tag-questions

What's the tag question for **has to** and **have to**? For example, *Tom and Clarissa **have to** buy some groceries, ...*?

Comment: The usual tag in your example is "don't they?" If the subject is singular then use "doesn't he/she?"

Comment: @BillJ - I think that British English speakers, and maybe more formal US speakers would say _Tom and Clarissa have to buy some groceries, haven't they?'. Joe has to tell his mother that he's gay, hasn't he?_

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Really, "*haven't they*"? I get the logic, but it sounds odd. But "*Tom and Clarissa have bought some groceries, haven't they?*" sounds completely fine. I wonder if I'm just used to it in the context of more common expressions..

Comment: @Joachim - you often see/hear Americans pairing 'have' (statement verb) with 'does' (tag verb) but I promise you a lot of Brits pair 'have' (statement verb) with 'have' (tag verb) but, see here https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13517/using-hasnt-he-in-question-tags

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using "hasn't he" in question tags](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13517/using-hasnt-he-in-question-tags)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I've noticed recently that speakers on BBC radio sometimes say "I don't", "doesn't he?" etc. where I would expect "I haven't", "hasn't he?".

Comment: @KateBunting -  I think informal tag questions can show English at its most lively - I think of Archie Bunker maybe saying 'He has to go to the turlet, don't he?' and the spread of the universally useful 'innit' in the UK.

Answer (score 5):

Note: the answer will vary between British and American English. Most verbs use "do" in the tag to stand for the verb: "I wear this scarf well, *don't I*?" (do I not). But a few, like "to be," use themselves: "You're sick, *aren't* you?" ("are you not").

**In British usage**, "have" usually does this too, and the answer would be "Tom and Clarissa have to buy some groceries, *haven't they*?"

**In American usage**, "have" is usually treated just like other verbs and the answer would be "Tom and Clarissa have to buy some groceries, *don't they*?"

See [this research paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/240703480_Tag_Questions_in_British_and_American_English) for a scholarly look at the difference—and note they observe that British English is more likely to use tag questions in general.

You could also use many other idiomatic tags, like "...right?" or "don't you think?", but these can be added to just about anything.

Comment: Why would you use past tense for 'have to'?

Comment: @KateBunting Oops, for some reason I read it as "Tom and Clarissa had to." Editing...

Comment: I always thought the rule of thumb was that 'have' and 'be'  are mirrored in the tag, all others have 'do' in the tag. He has a big head, hasn't he? She is Welsh, isn't she? You like beer, don't you? And for 'have to', in BrE tag could be either 'have' or 'do'.

Comment: All speakers, I think, use _have_ in the tag when _have_ is an auxiliary; but using it when _have_ is a full verb (including the composite _have to_) is becoming less common, and previous replies and comments indicate that it is even less common in American than British usage.

Comment: @AndyBonner You haven't answered the OP's question, which asked about tags with stative "have", as in _Tom and Clarissa have to buy some groceries_"

Comment: @BillJ - my answer is 'He has to do that, hasn't he?' but I'm British.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Good point, the BrE vs AmE difference was a big oversight. Edited

Comment: The choice of auxiliaries or modal verbs in tags also differs, with American English
preferring DO-tags and British English HAVE-tags; **this can be explained by the differences in the use of tenses in the two varieties and the predilection for HAVE GOT
constructions in anchors in British English** This is pretty in-depth study. https://www.lancaster.ac.uk/fass/projects/corpus/ZJU/xpapers/Tottie_tag_question.pdf

Comment: @AndyBonner I disagree. Most BrE speakers treat the stative "have" in the OP's example as a lexical verb just as most, if not all, speakers of AmE do. Lexical "have" has “do” in the tag, while auxiliary “have” has “have”.

Answer (score 3):

> *Tom and Clarissa have to buy some groceries, don't / haven't they?*

Whether the verb in the tag is a form of "do" or "have" depends on how "have" is treated in the anchor clause.

For those who treat it as a lexical verb, AmE speakers and many BrE; they select "do" in the tag.

Those speakers of BrE who treat it as an auxiliary verb select "have" in the tag.